# How to make cell reference static even after inserting a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use the sparkline formula on a fix `range("G:P")`.
Everyday i add another column next to column F into my sheet. So Column "G" becomes "I" and so on. The problem is that the formula does update the range aswell.

`=SPARKLINE($G54:BM54)`

to

`=SPARKLINE($I54:BM54)`

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: It should not be surprising that the address of a referenced cell changed when you moved the referenced cell - you told the spreadsheet that you cared about *that **cell*** - not that *address*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` or `INDIRECT`:

```
=SPARKLINE(INDEX(54:54;7):BM54;{"charttype"\"column";"negcolor"\"red";"color"\"green";"axis"\WAHR})
```

or

```
=SPARKLINE(INDIRECT("$G54:BM54");{"charttype"\"column";"negcolor"\"red";"color"\"green";"axis"\WAHR})
```